# Graph Of Step Functions

Tags: calculus, step-function

If we are asked to graph the step function $[\sqrt{x}]$ for $0 \leq x \leq 10$, I have seen a solution, which is given below,
[image]

what I am having doubts about is the closed circle at the end when $x=10$, if I were to graph it, it would be an open circle. Am I missing something here? Is there any cases where we have two closed circles in a step function graph?

Another question was to graph the step function $[x+\dfrac{1}{2}]$ on the interval $[-2,2]$, the solution is given as
[image]

shouldn't this also be an open circle at the end when $x=2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both filled circles indicate that the corresponding point belongs to the graph:

- $x = 10$ is in the domain and $[\sqrt{10}] = 3$
- $x = 2$ is in the domain and $[2+\frac{1}{2}] = 2$

The empty circles indicate that the corresponding point does not belong to the graph.

Comment: The reason why I am confused, is because the person who solved this question, solved other questions differently, you can see here: http://www.stumblingrobot.com/2015/07/16/draw-the-graphs-of-some-functions/

Comment: The other graphs has an open circle at the end, except for one graph which is the one I attached in the question.

Comment: @D.Qa : When looking at a), for example, I can see that the y-axis is too short. The function $x+[x]$ jumps at $x=2$ to $4$. So, the graph there is missing the full circle for point $(2,4)$.

Comment: @D.Qa Graph b) is also not correct. The filled circle for $(2,0)$ is missing since $2-[2] = 0$. To sum up: Lousy graphs. :-)

Comment: I think now I understood what you mean. To make sure what I understood is correct, looking at the graph attached up, the reason for why for example we have at $x=1.5$ a closed circle is because the floor function for [1.5+0.5] = 2, which corresponds to the 2 at the $y$-axis thus the closed circle. Same goes for [2+0.5]=2, thus we also add a closed circle? However, when the step function is $1$ then at $x=1.5$ it is open because the floor function is actually $2$ not $1$ however when we jump it is closed. Am I correct?

Comment: Exactly. Just imagine if you would draw the graphs without these circles. It would be not clear at jumps, which drawn endpoint belongs to the graph. So, one indicates this by empty and filled circles. It was good that you found it out for yourself that there was something wrong with the graphs on the page you linked.

Comment: Thank you so much, you cleared all my doubts.

Comment: You are welcome :-)