# Graph of $f(x)=x-[x]-\dfrac{1}{2}$

Tags: calculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have a question regarding this graph, for $f(x)=x-[x]-\dfrac{1}{2}$, where $[\cdot ]$ denotes the greatest integer function. My question is about the graph, why does the first slop has an open circle at $(-3,-0.5)$? shouldn't it be a close circle since $f(-3)=-3-[-3]-\dfrac{1}{2}=-0.5?$

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's a bug in your plotting software.

Comment: I agree. If $n$ is an integer, then $f(n)=-1/2$, not $0$.

Comment: I remember a similar problem you had here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3113840/graph-of-step-functions
you should finally quit using the site you mentioned there as the graphs there are erroneous.

Comment: @trancelocation Yes, I remember your comment there, it was very helpful, and you are correct, many of the graphs there were wrong. Definitely will stop using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if your software may be treating $[n]=n-\frac12$ for integer $n$

That would be halfway between $\lim\limits_{x \to n^{-}} [x]=n-1$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to n^{+}} [x]=n$, but it is not a common usage of a floor function aimed at producing integers